# Why Does MariaDB behave differentyly when an arbitrarily high limit is placed on a subquery?

Tags: sql, mariadb

The following query ends up using a "filesort" in MariaDB 5.5.40.  It takes about 9 seconds to complete.  Both `sos` and `quotes` are fairly large tables, but nothing crazy.

```
explain
select  SQL_NO_CACHE
`quotes`.`QuoteName`
FROM 
`worknet`.`quotes`
LEFT JOIN `worknet`.`sostatus` AS `sostatusDB` ON `quotes`.`dnum`=`sostatusDB`.`so`  
LEFT JOIN 
(SELECT `dnum` from `worknet`.`sos`) AS `sosStatusDb`
ON `quotes`.`dnum`=`sosStatusDB`.`dnum` 
where `quotes`.`deleted` IS NULL
ORDER BY `quotes`.`dateModified` DESC 
LIMIT 100

1   PRIMARY <derived2>  ALL                 100 Using where; Using temporary; Using filesort
1   PRIMARY sos index   PRIMARY SONUM   18      179433  Using where; Using index; Using join buffer (flat, BNL join)
2   DERIVED quotes  index       date_modified   5       100 Using where
```

However, if I create an artificial limit in the subquery, everything changes (for the better!).  I replace the subquery line with the limit line below:

```
(SELECT `dnum` from `worknet`.`sos` LIMIT 18446744073709551615)  AS `sosStatusDb`

1   PRIMARY <derived2>  ALL                 100 Using where; Using temporary; Using filesort
1   PRIMARY <derived3>  ALL                 179433  Using where; Using join buffer (flat, BNL join)
3   DERIVED sos index       SONUM   18      179433  Using index
2   DERIVED quotes  index       date_modified   5       100 Using where
```

They query now takes .078 seconds, instead of 9.1 seconds.

So obviously, the limit is convincing the engine use a better algorithm, but why?  The limit I have imposed is huge (2^64-1), and affects nothing, but results in a vastly improved time.  This seems like a bug in the optimizer, but I cannot find any other way to improve the performance.

Comment: First explain does not look complete

Comment: For some reason maria only reported two rows of the explain.  I put in the explain from mysql instead.

Comment: Why do you use a nested query instead of just left joining `sos` table?

Comment: it's not really relevant to this discussion, but my original query was more complicated, and the subquery contained a cast of char to int for speedier join purposes.  in order to isolate the issue better, I took that part out, but I still have the subquery.

Comment: It **IS** relevant. You are asking about performance of one query, then you show us another. Well, don't expect to hear anything relevant then.

Comment: Sorry if I was unclear.  the behavior above occurs when using the queries above.  So any previous queries that I didn't show you are not relevant.  You asked why I had a subquery--the reason is because my original query (again, not analyzed or included here) had a good reason to use it.  To isolate the issue I removed some things, including the reason for the subquery--but this doesn't change the fact that the subquery acts differently when an aritifical limit is included!